# Использование протокола WebSocket между PHP-сервером и JavaScript-клиентом

Tags: php, javascript, websocket, поиск-библиотек

Какие библиотеки могут помочь в реализации сокета между сервером на PHP и клиентом на JavaScript? Пробовал разные библиотеки, но они не дружат между собой. Может, кто-то уже сталкивался с такого рода задачей?

Comment: а что пробовал и как? что значит "не дружат между собой"?

Comment: Вот такую библиотеку пробовал https://code.google.com/archive/p/phpwebsocket/ но как не пытался ее заставить работать никак, ни на локалке ни на VPS не получилось. Cервер подымается а клиент не может соединится. failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Есть также библиотека socket.io, но насколько я понял она для Node.js и чтобы заставить ее работать с сервером на PHP нужно библиотеку у которой миллион зависимостей тем более через composer.

Answer (score 0):

Для реализации сокетов на PHP можно использовать [Ratchet](http://socketo.me), который базируется на ReactPHP, Guzzle и Symfony. Связать клиент с ним можно простым нативным [WebSocket](https://learn.javascript.ru/websockets) классом. Однако не рекомендовал бы использовать PHP в качестве WebSocket сервера.

Если вас не утруждает использовать NodeJS, то лучше прибегните к [Socket.io 2.0](https://socket.io). Так вы сможете связать Ajax логику с реалтайм (сокетами). И вдобавок используйте PM2 для мониторинга и запуска сервера в кластерном режиме.